# why is the exit window button work but the exit button in the game does not work?

Tags: python, pygame

i'm making a start menu for my game but when i hit the exit button i made in the start menu, it doesn't exit. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I tried making a function for the exit, put it in the code that exit the game with the window exit button, but nothing worked.

```
import pygame
import os
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, 16, 2, 262144)
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*


pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 
'intro.ogg'))
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.3)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)  

FPS = 60
white = (255,255,255)
grey = (128,128,128)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
orange = (255,128,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
green = (0,255,0)
Lgreen = (128,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
Lblue = (0,255,255)
purple = (255,0,255)
pink = (255,0,127)

pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Universe')
Title = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Title.png')
Play = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Play.png')
Option = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Option.png')
Exit = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Exit.png')
LinePX = pygame.image.load('Graphics/LinePX.png')
LineO = pygame.image.load('Graphics/LineO.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('Video/bg.mpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
bgE = pygame.image.load('Graphics/transparent.png')
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()


movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()


y = 235
y1 = 3000



cnt = 0
playing = True
while playing:
    cnt+=1
    if cnt>=1870:
        cnt=0
        movie.rewind()
        movie.play()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                if y == 426:
                    movie.stop()
                    playing = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()      
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y += 1
                if y == 3236:
                    y = 235
                    y1 = 3000
                if y == 236:
                    y = 425
                    y1 = 3000
                if y == 426:
                    y1 =335
                    y = 3235

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y += 1
                if y == 236:
                    y = 3235
                    y1 = 335
                if y == 3236:
                    y1 = 3000
                    y = 425
                if y == 426:
                    y1 = 3000
                    y = 235

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                movie.stop()
                playing = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

   screen.blit(movie_screen,(0, 0))
   screen.blit(Title, (360, 0))
   screen.blit(Play, (460, 250))
   screen.blit(Exit, (460, 450))
   screen.blit(LinePX, (482.5, y))
   screen.blit(LineO, (482.5, y1))
   screen.blit(Option, (460, 350))
   screen.blit(bgE, (-100, 0))
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(FPS)
```

i expected it to exit the window but instead it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's not really clear from the small section of code what is happening.  How is the button-clicked event handled in the main loop?  Maybe when the quitting code is activated, `post` a `pygame.QUIT` event back to the main loop, e.g.: `pygame.event.post( pygame.QUIT, {} )`.

Comment: i updated my code

Comment: What does the `quitgame()` function do? if it sets `playing = False` similar to how you handle a `pygame.QUIT` event it should work. Also, you're catching a Keypad Enter key-press, you may instead want `pygame.K_RETURN`. Creating a [mcve] will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main loop runs as long as `playing` is `True`.

> ```
> playing = True
> while playing:
>     # [...]
> ```

When the `pygame.QUIT` event is handled, `playing` is set `False` the main loop condition is fails:

> ```
> if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>     playing = False
>     # [...]
> ```

Note, [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) doesn't terminate the loop, but it uninitialize all pygame modules, which will cause an exception in the following, if it is done in the *middle* of the application.

If you want to quit the application by the keypad enter key [`pygame.K_KP_ENTER`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html), the you've to do the same when the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event is handled:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
        playing = False
```

Or you've to send a `pygame.QUIT` event by [`pygame.event.post()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post):

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
        pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pygame.QUIT))
```

Comment: you are right, but i deleted some code that detect where the y is when I hit enter and make it do what i want. I found out my y detection code isn't working on the enter key. For example, when i made it print a random text. it wouldn't print it.

Comment: no, even with y >= 426 it still doesn't work. Why only the up and down keys work with the y detector but enter doesn't

Comment: removing the y += 1 will make the arrow key scroll go the opposite way. This is because when pressing the arrow key it meet all the value and make them go in order which then in human view, it go backwards.

Comment: that worked, i found the problem and fixed it, thank you.